# Is there any way to start the game with the starters of the second generation?

Tags: pokemon-go

As generation 2 has now been released, I am quite curious about something. If you start a new account now, are you able to select any of the three generation 2 starters (Totodile, Cyndaquil, and Chikorita)? Or can you only select one from the first generation?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because it's a rather simple thing to test by making a new account.

Comment: @TimmyJim It is, but I didn't want to create another account just to test that. That's why i asked. :p Also it's nice to have the answer there for the newcomers to the game too.

Comment: Not that starters really mean anything in Go anyhow...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you don't get to pick from the new starters.

If you start a new account, you only get the original starters (Bulbasaur, Charmander and Squirtle). You can still get the pikachu if you keep running out of sight for 5 times (so the 6th time an additional Pikachu will spawn).